# drupal 7 forms : custom rendering

Tags: forms, drupal-7

drupal_render($form) works fine for my purposes in general, but there are cases where I'd like a form to have a different layout style
(specifically I'd like all the fields and submit button to appear in one horizontal row)
Is there a way to specify a different rendering for a specific form, and leave the rest with the default rendering for the theme?

Answer (score 0):

If it's the layout you want to change, most likely, you'd want to change the CSS, not the markup.

If you want to display all the fields and submit button in a row, you could change them into blocks and "float: left;" them.